# generated docx with opentbs converted by unoconv and libreoffice

Tags: pdf-generation, docx, libreoffice, opentbs, unoconv

For some reason I am expecting a strange behaviour.
When I am merging my docx template with opentbs, it works all fine and it looks correct in the generated docx.

But now I need to convert the docx into a pdf where I am using unoconv and libreoffice on mac OS X 10.11.

when I do this, all strings with multiple lines (which are displayed correctly in the docx) will be displayed as single line in the pdf.
Also if I open the generated docx with libreoffice, all multi line strings will be displayed as single line.

I figured out, that I can use `;strconv=no`.
This will then do exactly the opposite. All multi line strings in the docx will be displayed as single line, but in libreoffice or converting to pdf with unoconv they are displayed correctly with multi lines.

anyone has a solution for this problem?

Comment: Have you tried to generate `ODT` documents instead of `DOCX`? Since you're using LibreOffice unoconv to convert the documents, you will have a better compatibility if you also create a ODT document. However, without a model or your code, it will be hard to pinpoint the issue.